# JQuery Select Based on multiple attributes

Tags: jquery

I would like to select the (only) textbox where name = "something" and id="somethingElse". I can't quite get the selector (searchByIDandNameCriteria) right. This is an all (not any) multiple selector:

```
function setItemValue(type)
{
    var searchByIDandNameCriteria = "[id='" + itemNum + "'][name='" + type + "']";

    // example searchByIDandNameCriteria = "[id='12345'][name='case']"

    var valueToChange = $(searchByIDandNameCriteria).val();
}
```

Comment: `id`s must be unique for each elements on the document so selecting by `id` only should be sufficient. Why do you want to include the `name` too?

Comment: It would help to know what context you're using this in. Sounds like you're trying to manipulate elements from a similar set that differentiate numerically. You should probably consider just using concatenated numerical IDs or just the index values of the element.

Comment: I have two textboxes for each item in inventory, now identified with the inventory number as the id (two of them) and the type (bottle or case) as the name attribute, and I was hoping to send the parameters straight into the AJAX call. No biggie, thanks guys

Comment: update for the benefit of fellow developers: try the title tag, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID's of elements need to be unique in a page, so everything you are trying with a selection of a name is irrelevant as you can select the element by its ID. If your ID isn't unique, you will need to change your html or you won't be able to select those elements correctly.

If you want to select multiple elements, give them a class for example (classes can be shared by multiple elements) and select the elements with

```
$('.elementsClass')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass two parameter in your function

1. for **type**
2. for **id**

   ```
    function setItemValue(type, itemNum ){

     var searchByIDandNameCriteria = "input[id='" + itemNum + "'][name='" + type + "']";

     // example searchByIDandNameCriteria = "[id='12345'][name='case']"

    var valueToChange = $(searchByIDandNameCriteria).val();

   }
   ```